# Show both radio button and checkbox based on database value

Tags: java, android

I m working on radio button and checkbox button. The value 0 is for radio and 1 is for checkbox. Based on these values, I would like to display It on the screen. There might be both radio and checkboxes.

Right now, The value im getting as 0 and 1 from the database, it is just setting either radio button or checkbox for all attributes. It should display checkbox for value 1 and radio button for Value of 0.

Here is the code:

```
                           if(multiSelect != null)
                                {
                                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mMain);
                                    radioButton.setText(name_price);
                                    radioButton.setId(i + 6);
                                    radioButton.setTextSize(12);
                                    radioButton.setTag(attributes.get(num));
                                    radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                                    {
                                        radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                    }
                                    setTextFont(radioButton, "Museo_Slab.otf");

                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            1f);
                                    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                                    radioButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                    attr_layout[j].addView(radioButton);
                                    num++;

                                    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {
                                                ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                                                if (isChecked)
                                                {

                                                    float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                                                    item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                                                    item_price_text.setText(priceStr);

                                                    selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                                                }
                                                // If the attributes are not checked

                                            } catch (Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                GSLogger.e(ex);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                else // if the multiSelect is 1
                                {
                                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(mMain);
                                    checkBox.setText(name_price);
                                    checkBox.setId(i + 6);
                                    checkBox.setTextSize(12);
                                    checkBox.setTag(attributes.get(num));
                                    checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                                    {
                                        checkBox.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                    }
                                    setTextFont(checkBox, "Museo_Slab.otf");

                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            1f);
                                    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                                    checkBox.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                    attr_layout[j].addView(checkBox);
                                    num++;

                                    // Reads the value depending on attribute User Selects
                                    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {
                                                ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                                                if (isChecked)
                                                {

                                                    float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                                                    item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                                                    item_price_text.setText(priceStr);
                                                    selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                                                }

                                            } catch (Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                GSLogger.e(ex);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Based on the items group defined say it is 0 or 1, it should display it on screen. If the group has both options, then the screen should display both radio for 0 value and checkbox for 1 value.

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition allows only either of these to be added. You should check if the value is 0 then add radio button and if value is 1 it should add checkbox. You have implemented if else block instead of 2 if blocks.

```
   if(value == 0)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mMain);
        radioButton.setText(name_price);
        radioButton.setId(i + 6);
        radioButton.setTextSize(12);
        radioButton.setTag(attributes.get(num));
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        {
            radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
        }
        setTextFont(radioButton, "Museo_Slab.otf");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1f);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

        radioButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

        attr_layout[j].addView(radioButton);
        num++;

        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                try
                {
                    ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                    if (isChecked)
                    {

                        float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                        item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                        item_price_text.setText(priceStr);

                        selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                    }
                    // If the attributes are not checked

                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    GSLogger.e(ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if(value==1)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(mMain);
        checkBox.setText(name_price);
        checkBox.setId(i + 6);
        checkBox.setTextSize(12);
        checkBox.setTag(attributes.get(num));
        checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        {
            checkBox.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
        }
        setTextFont(checkBox, "Museo_Slab.otf");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1f);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

        checkBox.setLayoutParams(lp);

        attr_layout[j].addView(checkBox);
        num++;

        // Reads the value depending on attribute User Selects
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                try
                {
                    ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                    if (isChecked)
                    {

                        float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                        item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                        item_price_text.setText(priceStr);
                        selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    GSLogger.e(ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you check on debugging what value you are getting from database and does the control goes in first if loop

Comment: I have both 0 and 1 value. Some groups should display only checkbox based on the value, and some radio button based on the user input

Comment: I have both 0 and 1 value for Multiselect

Comment: Then is control going into both if blocks?

Comment: It is going only to checkboxes. not going for the radio  even if the value is 0

Comment: That means value obtained from database is 1 only.

Comment: No. When i debug, i can see 0 and 1

Comment: attr_layout[j].addView(checkBox); This j value is a loop count?. Could you check if both radio and checkbox are added at same "j" element of the loop.

Comment: But, for items i want user to select only one item for radio. Right now, User can select multiple items in radio box

Comment: You need to use a radio group instead of radio button which allows single selection

Comment: When i use radio group, i do get lot of errors like setTEx]

Comment: Jacky google the use of radio group. It is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

change if condition when you get 0 from db then set radio button otherwise set checkbox

```
  if(value == 0) 
    {
                                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mMain);
                                radioButton.setText(name_price);
                                radioButton.setId(i + 6);
                                radioButton.setTextSize(12);
                                radioButton.setTag(attributes.get(num));
                                radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                                {
                                    radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                }
                                setTextFont(radioButton, "Museo_Slab.otf");

                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        1f);
                                lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                                radioButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                attr_layout[j].addView(radioButton);
                                num++;

                                radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                                            if (isChecked)
                                            {

                                                float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                                                item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                                                item_price_text.setText(priceStr);

                                                selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                                            }
                                            // If the attributes are not checked

                                        } catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            GSLogger.e(ex);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(mMain);
                                checkBox.setText(name_price);
                                checkBox.setId(i + 6);
                                checkBox.setTextSize(12);
                                checkBox.setTag(attributes.get(num));
                                checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                                {
                                    checkBox.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                }
                                setTextFont(checkBox, "Museo_Slab.otf");

                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        1f);
                                lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

                                checkBox.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                attr_layout[j].addView(checkBox);
                                num++;

                                // Reads the value depending on attribute User Selects
                                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            ItemAttributes itemAttributes = (ItemAttributes) buttonView.getTag();

                                            if (isChecked)
                                            {

                                                float total_price = current_price + attr_price;

                                                item.setItemPrice(total_price + "");

                                                item_price_text.setText(priceStr);
                                                selectedAttributes.add(itemAttributes);
                                            }

                                        } catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            GSLogger.e(ex);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```